# Pass output parameters in a template object in Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, dynamicparameters

I have stored procedures with input and output parameters. I have separate classes for input and output classes. So, I want to create Dynamic Parameters using template objects instead of adding each property.

For Eg:

```
public class StudentInput {
 public StudentInput() {
   this.StudentId = 1;
 }
 public int StudentId {get; set}
}

public class StudentOutput {
 public string StudentName {get; set;}
 public string FavSubject {get; set;}
 public int Grade {get; set;}
 public int YearOfJoining {get; set;}
}
```

I have a stored procedure `[SP_GetStudentData]` that takes StudentId as input and returns StudentName, FavSubject, Grade and YearOfJoining.

Using Dapper, I wrote the following code.

```
DynamicParameters ip = new DynamicParameters(new StudentInput());
DynamicParameters op = new DynamicParameters(new StudentOutput());

ip.AddDynamicParameters(op);
```

// ***`Here is the question. How do I tell Dapper that op is a output parameters object? How do I add ParameterDirection output to each of the properties in this object?`***

```
SqlMapper.ExecuteSP(connection, SP_GetStudentData, ip, CommandType.StoredProcedure)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the SQL Server can only return scalar object as output parameters. So you can't map an output parameter to your `StudentOutput` class. Just return the values you need as a resultset (using a SELECT statement inside the SP) and then map that resultset to your class.

```
var result = connection.Query("SP_GetStudentData @studentId", new { studentId = (new StudentInput()).StudentId }, commandType:StoredProcedure)
```